# char data type is not giving negative numbers by adding a positive number to the character which is holding maximum positive value

Tags: c

I am trying to add '1' to a character which is holding maximum positive value it can hold. It is giving 0 as output instead of giving -256.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    signed char c = 255;
    printf("%d\n", c + 1 );
}

O / P : 0
c + 2 = 1;
c + 3 = 2;
```

As per my understanding, it should give negative numbers once it reaches the maximum limit (). Is this correct? I am testing on Ubuntu.

Comment: `which is holding maximum positive value it can hold.` no, maximal value for signed char is 127, so 255 is converted into -1 during assignment

Comment: `signed char` encodes values [-128...127].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `signed char` is very often 8-bit encoding values [-128...127].

`signed char c = 255;` is attempting to initialize `c` to a value outside the `signed char` range.

It is implementation behavior what happens next.  Very commonly `255` is converted "mod" 256 to the value of -1.

```
signed char c = 255;
printf("%d\n", c     );  // -1 expected
printf("%d\n", c + 1 );  //  0 expected
```

---

> As per my understanding, it should give negative numbers once it reaches the maximum limit (). Is this correct?

No.  Adding 1 to the maximum `int` value is *undefined behavior*.   There is no *should*.  It might result in a negative number, might not, might exit code - it is not defined.

Had code been

```
signed char c = 127;
printf("%d\n", c + 1 );
```

`c + 1` would be 128 and `"128\n"` would be printed as `c + 1` is an `int` operation with an in range `int` sum.

Comment: just a question.  Isn't signed overflow undefined behaviour so wrapping around isn't allowed?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Signed overflow is undefined behavior, but there is no overflow here.  `signed char c = 255;` is not overflow. it is an out-of-range conversion.  "Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is
implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised."  C17dr 6.3.1.3  `c + 1` is `-1 + 1` --> no overflow.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I knew there was no overflow, but his code example was different than his question.  He said "I am trying to add '1' to a character which is holding maximum positive value it can hold. ... As per my understanding, it should give negative numbers once it reaches the maximum limit"  Which clearly (to me at least) means he thinks that you can do overflow and expect it to work.  And, of course, the code example implies that 255 is the largest value a signed char can hold - but that wasn't really his question so I just wanted to make sure....

Comment: @JerryJeremiah And even if `c` were initialized to 127, `c + 1` would not result in signed overflow. The value of `c` would still be promoted to `int`, and `c + 1` would yield the `int` value 128. There are no arithmetic operations on integer types narrower than `int` and `unsigned int`. Values of any narrower types are promoted before the arithmetic operator is applied.

Comment: @KeithThompson  Thanks.  That's what I was trying to figure out.  I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

There's several implicit conversions to keep track of here:

- `signed char c = 255;` Is a conversion of the constant `255` which has type `int`, into a smaller `signed char`. This is "lvalue conversion through assignment" (initialization follows the rules of assignment) where the right operand gets converted to the type of the left.

  The actual conversion from a large signed type to a small signed type follows this rule:

  > Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the
  > result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

  In practice, the very likely conversion to happen on a two's complement computer is that you end up with the signed char having the decimal value equivalent to `0xFF`, which is `-1`.
- `c + 1` is an operation with two operands of types `signed char` and `int` respectively. For the + operator, it means that *the usual arithmetic conversions* are performed, see [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules).

  Meaning `c` gets converted to `int` and the operation is carried out on `int` type, which is also the type of the result.
- `printf("%d\n", stuff );` The functions like `printf` accepting a variable number of arguments undergo an oddball conversion rule called *the default argument promotions*. In case of integers, it means that the integer promotions (see link above) are carried out. If you pass `c + 1` as parameter, then the type is `int` and no promotion takes place. But if you had just passed `c`, then it gets implicitly promoted to `int` as per these rules. Which is why using `%d` together with character type actually works, even though it's the wrong conversion specifier for printing characters.

---

> As per my understanding, it should give negative numbers once it reaches the maximum limit (). Is this correct?

If you simply do `signed char c = 127; c++;` then that's a signed overflow, undefined behavior with no predictable outcome.

If you do `signed char c = 127; ... c + 1` then there's no overflow because of the implicit promotion to `int`.

If you do `unsigned char c = 255; c++;` then there is a well-defined wrap around since this is an unsigned type. `c` will become zero. Signed types do not have such a well-defined wrap around - they overflow instead.

In practice, signed number overflow is artificial nonsense invented by the C standard. All well-known computers just set an overflow and/or carry bit when you do overflow on assembler level, properly documented and well-defined by the core manual. The reason it turns "undefined behavior" in C is mainly because C allows for nonsensical signedness formats like one's complement or signed magnitude, that may have padding bits, trap representations or other such exotic, mostly fictional stuff.

Though nowadays, optimizing compilers take advantage of overflow not being allowed to happen, in order to generate more efficient code. Which is unfortunate, since we could have had both fast and 100% deterministic code if 2's complement was the only allowed format.